# Swift Cache JSON Request

Tags: ios, swift, caching, cache-control

I have an IOS app that fetching data from my backend i'm using Alamofire Lib and i have already downloaded and parsed the JSON data successfully.
Now i want to enhance the user experience by adding cache data to my app, This is my first time to use it and after reading many articles i got confused about **How To Use Cache Strategy** .
All what i need is to get the right idea for below queries

**1.Online Connectivity (let Assume the following scenarios ):**

A - The user open's my app for the first time -> the app will download and display the data on **mainview** -> the user navigate to another view -> **Now** if i cached the response how to tell the app to use the cached data instead of making a new request when the user navigate back to **mainview**?

B - For the same scenario of **A** if the first response retrieved the first 10 objects from the Backend and this response is cached -> other app users make some new posts to the backend lets (say 20 new post) -> **Now** how to tell my app that there is anew data on the server go and make anew request and don't depend on the cached one ?

**2.Offline Connectivity :** 
In my opinion i think its the same case for above scenarios A -> no connection -> go to cache

connection successful -> (same as scenario B) -> check for new data -> if exist -> make new request -> no new data -> go to cache

I hope that some one could help me with this issue

Comment: Is your server response sending correct caching headers? This should automatically be managed if your response indicates how long to cache data for and uses ETags.

Comment: Okay , so the whole idea is about the server cache headers? right ?

Comment: Yes. You can still manually cache if you want, or use something like AwesomeCache. But as long as your server uses the correct headers it will cache automatically.

Comment: I will try and back with results